# Why Does MATLAB 2D Char Array turn into Python 1D array?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I am using Scipy to load MATLAB 2D matrix into Python. In MATLAB the MAT is 32x40 Char matrix. Each index has one character in it. However, when loaded into Python it becomes a `(32,)` `numpy` `array` with all the characters now treated as 32 rows of strings instead of 32 rows of characters with max length of 40 characters. How do I go about breaking back up this 32 row array back into a 2D array with 32 rows and 40 columns of characters?

```
a = np.array([])
matdata = spio.loadmat(misspath)
a = np.append(a, matdata['D_package'])
a_data = matdata['a_data']
```

Python `numpy` `(32,)`:

```
Out[545]: 
array([['PLPBTKNLYLHDFWVCEVTTNMTTBFFVAGLDEGHFFFTP'],
['PRiDAEo    rooWEnaFFDAKAuSOrRERltrAFFCCeo'],
['FltRGFUrAGFtwSxxLLLLLrIAossDGDPAAAAsw'],
[' FKDDFWa plG iiFDGGSSD\x00\x02u3t te\x003411te'],
.....
```

Original MATLAB `(32,40)`:

```
val = 
PLPBTKNLYLHDFWVCEVTTNMTTBFFVAGLDEGHFFFTP
PRiDAEo    rooWEnaFFDAKAuSOrRERltrAFFCCeo
FltRGFUrAGFtwSxxLLLLLrIAossDGDPAAAAsw
 FKDDFWa plG iiFDGGSSD\x00\x02u3t te\x003411te
....
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want. If `a = ['qwe', 'rty']`, then `a_mat = map(list, a)`.

Comment: This returns a map memory item in Python 3.6. I included the outputs to give more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Until R2016b MATLAB didn't have a *string* datatype, but stored strings as *character vectors*, and that's how most MATLAB code is still written. So `loadmat` reasonably assumes that a *n*-dimensional character array from MATLAB should be interpreted as a *n-1*-dimensional string array.

If you actually want an array in Python where each element is a single character, it's easy to convert using list comprehensions:

```
>>> a = numpy.array([ ['hot'],['foo'],['pie'] ])

array([['hot'],
       ['foo'],
       ['pie']],
      dtype='<U3')

>>> numpy.array([[c for c in w[0]] for w in a])

array([['h', 'o', 't'],
   ['f', 'o', 'o'],
   ['p', 'i', 'e']],
  dtype='<U1')
```